# How to turn multiline command output into comma separated string in batch file

Tags: git, batch-file

I'm trying to parse the result of `git diff --name-only` to construct a single string containing all the paths of the changed files, separated by commas. For example, the diff result might look like:

```
src/changed/file1.txt
src/changed/file2.txt
src/changed/file3.txt
```

and I want to arrive at

```
"src/changed/file1.txt,src/changed/file2.txt,src/changed/file3.txt"
```

I have zero experience in writing batch scripts, and so far I have pieced together this which does not work:

```
Set concatenatedList = ""
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD HEAD~1') do call :parse_results "%%a"
echo %concatenatedList%
pause
goto :EOF

:parse_results
Set output=%~1
echo output:%output%
Set source_dir=%output:~0,3%
IF "%source_dir%"=="src" Set concatenatedList = %concatenatedList%,%output%
goto :EOF
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: remove the space in the set command before and after the equal sign, move the command to the end. `set "concatenatedList=%concatenatedList%%output%,` then we can get rid of the trailling comma in the line before `echo %concatenatedList%` `set concatenatedList=%concatenatedList:~-1%`

Comment: Your code does not match your question. The question asks for a result of, `"src/changed/file1.txt,src/changed/file2.txt,src/changed/file3.txt"`, from the command `git diff --name-only`, and gave the output to help us. Now the command has changed to `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD HEAD~1` and the result, `src/changed/file1.txt,src/changed/file2.txt,src/changed/file3.txt,src`. Please provide code to match the stated requirements.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard That did the trick! Never even thought of the spaces being a reason for the concatenation to fail. I will accept this as an answer if you add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` command uses whitespace as part of the variable  name before the `=` and as part of the variable value after the `=`. So remove the whitespace and double quote the string.

```
set "concatenatedList=%concatenatedList%%output,"
```

You can also eliminate the trailing comma by adding this line before the `echo` line.

```
set "concatenatedList=%concatenatedList:~-1%"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Warning :** This answer assumes you're executing this in bash context with [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) available (like a linux shell or Git for Windows)

---

I'm not experienced enough in bash to call it "a correct way" to do this, but if it can help, here's how I'd do it :

```
 git diff --name-only | sed -z 's/\n/\,/g'
```

(`-z` replaces the end of line character in sed context)

Beware, however, of the last trailing `,` that would be produced and might be unwanted, depending on your needs.

Comment: Is this assuming the OP has `sed` available on a windows device?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard You're very right about that assumption, I should disclaim it clearly. Editing.